# XCode Debugging

Tags: c++, xcode, debugging

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

typedef struct Record
{
    std::string  name;
    bool   isVisible;
    int    index;
}Record;

vector<Record> recordVector;

int main (int argc, char * const argv[])
{
    Record tmpRecord = {"c++", true, 1};

    for (int i = 0 ; i < 15; ++i) {
        recordVector.push_back(tmpRecord);
}

    return 0;
}
```

When I am debugging this and hover my cursor at recordVector variable to see the entire contents of this, its showing just 10(0-9) only, also its also not showing full contents in memory browser also. Although this vector has 15 contents in it.

Any clue for tweaking out this will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure you are using the "Debug" build configuration. Debug builds generate debug symbols and disable code optimization, otherwise the information shown by the debugger may be inaccurate.

You can found more info about this topic in the [Mac OS X Reference Library](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/XcodeDebugging/010-Debugging_Essentials/debugging_essentials.html).